# Parar eventos multiplos Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```
$('input[name=buscar]').on( "keydown keypress keyup", function( event ) {
    console.log('foi');
});
```

Todas as vezes que digito, os 3 eventos são acionados. Como faço para que apenas 1 seja acionado, ao invés dos três? ou seja, cliquei no botão, disparou o primeiro evento, vez oque deveria fazer e pronto...

Comment: Se for identificar o evento adicionado  pode ser da forma citada abaixo, se for para executar apenas um evento especifico remova os demais.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues A maneira que você citou da certo. Mas teve uma vez, acredito que utilizei alguma função, onde ela parava os demais eventos, então eu não precisa verificar evento por evento, ele disparava uma vez, e não realizava os demais. Mas não recordo a maneira que fiz isso. ATT

Comment: Se não tiver um caso especifico fica difícil ajudar, estes três eventos trabalham "quase" no mesmo tempo, talvez você deva analisar qual evento é ideal e utiliza-lo

Comment: Qual a razão de teres os 3 eventos associados a esse input?

Comment: @Sergio Anos atrás tive problemas utilizando apenas 1 evento, daí para frente sempre utilizo os três... Pois de nenhuma forma irá deixar de pegar um evento...

Comment: @abcd ok, mas adicionar os 3 pesa na performance do browser, e gera problemas como este que estás a ter. Deves sempre adicionar só o necessário à funcionalidade que precisas. Nalguns casos pode ser que precises mais do que um. Qual é a funcionalidade que procuras?

Comment: @Sergio Em relação a hoje, Gera alguns problemas de visualização, minimos que não irão interferir. Mas no passado0 já tive problemas quando utilizei ajax, pois solicita 3 vezes... O que o usuário GabrieRodrigues respondeu resolve. Mas, anos atrás, eu tenho em mente que resolvi este mesmo problema de uma forma mais "elegante", onde se houvesse disparado algum dos 3 eventos, ele não repetia os demais... Mas por ter dúvida, eu não recordo o que fiz naquela época. ATT

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que esteja executando por ser três eventos diferentes mas que seriam executados ao "mesmo tempo". Vou explicar:

**keyup()**: o evento ocorre quando a tecla volta a posição original no teclado (exemplo: quando você solta a tecla).

**keydown()**: o evento ocorre quando a tecla é pressionada.

**keypress()**: o evento ocorre quando a tecla é pressionada.

A diferença entre keydown() e keypress() é que o segundo não é capturado quando as teclas ctrl, alt ou shift são pressionadas.

Logo, se você aperta uma tecla, passará pelos 3 "estados" apresentados acima, para disparar apenas um, você poderia utilizar apenas uma das funções e remover as outras.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar o tipo de evento e colocar em uma condição para separar onde cada evento:

```
$('input[name=buscar]').on("keydown keypress keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.type === 'keydown') {
    console.log('1');
  } else if (event.type === 'keypress') {
    console.log('2');
  } else if (event.type === 'keyup') {
    console.log('3');
  }
});
```

Ou encadear vários eventos.

```
$('input[name=buscar]').on("keydown", function() {
  console.log('1');
}).on('keypress', function() {
  console.log('2');
}).on('keyup', function() {
  console.log('3');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você está utilizando esses eventos em um input, creio que o código abaixo seja a maneira mais simples de solucionar o seu problema:

```
$('input[name=buscar]').change( function() {
  console.log('foi');
});
```

Comment: Sua opção pode dar certo... Mas em minha situação em especifica, com todo o código, houve algumas modificações indesejadas nos eventos. ATT